# How to manage dependency arrays with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-component

Suppose I've got two variables varA and varB. I only want to do something to varA in the event the varB changes. I could write something to the effect of...

```
useEffect(()=> {
  DO SOMETHING TO varA;
}, [varB])
```

If I do this REACT will throw a warning in the console about a missing dependenecy, varA and ask that it be added to the array. But doing so will create behavior I do not want. How can I handle the warning in this situation?

Comment: Ignore the warning. You are correct in your thinking. You do not need the other variable

Comment: What kind of operation you want to perform on varA? you just need it's previous value?

Answer (score 1):

One of the rules of React hooks is that `useEffect` *must* include all variables that it references in its dependency array. That's why you're getting the error. You can have additional variables, like `varB`, but you cannot exclude one, otherwise you could run into some wonky behavior.

A way around it is to use a `ref`, which allows you to store the value in a way that never triggers a render. The ref will need to be included in the dependency array, but since it never changes it won't trigger the `useEffect` again.

```
const varARef = useRef(varA)

useEffect(()=> {
  DO SOMETHING TO varARef.current;
}, [varARef, varB])
```

Note that if you do want `varARef.current` to stay in sync with `varA`, you'll want to add a line for that:

```
const varARef = useRef(varA)
varARef.current = varA

useEffect(()=> {
  DO SOMETHING TO varARef.current;
}, [varARef, varB])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to update the state of a variable using its current state the best way to do it is using a **callback** inside setState.

**If you change your code like this no issue will be triggered.**

```
[varB, setVarB] = useState("");
[counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

useEffect(()=>{
 setCounter(currentCounter => currentCounter+1);
},[varB]) // No warning here
```

Full answer: [useEffect has a missing dependency when updating state based on current value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69410303/react-hook-useeffect-has-a-missing-dependency-when-updating-state-based-on-curre/69410304#69410304)

Comment: An excellent pattern to be familiar with! If `varA` is a state, and if the "something" that OP wants to do is change the state of `varA`, then this is the best solution.