# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency when updating state based on current value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies

I need to update the current value of a React state based on its current value. However, using the current state will trigger the warning: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency`. How can I update the state?

For simplicity suppose that I have to count the times another state is updated:

```
[myState, setMyState] = useState("");
[counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

useEffect(()=>{
 setCounter(counter+1);
},[myState]) // React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'counter'
```

However, I **can't** add `counter` among the **dependencies** since the useEffect will enter in an **infinite loop** (since hook will be triggered again because of `counter` change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to implement this type of change is using a callback inside the `setState` method. By using a callback we can access the **current value** of our state, without the need to reference the object containing the state directly. In this way, no warning is issued and the counter can be implemented directly.

```
[myState, setMyState] = useState("");
[counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

useEffect(()=>{
 setCounter(currentCounter => currentCounter+1);
},[myState]) // No warning here
```

Or if you need more complex actions:

```
useEffect(()=>{
 setCounter(currentCounter => {
   //do stuff
   return currentCounter+1
 });
},[myState]) // No warning here
```

Full documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Comment: @NiceBooks thanks for the link, I forgot to mention documentation. This is a pattern that I see very often asked in stack overflow, so I decided to do a post that links the issue that React raises with this solution.